# Writing conventions / pronunciations for words with っ

Tags: pronunciation, rōmaji, gemination, music

I'm currently trying to figure out on how to do karaoke for some songs and I got a bit confused about the following. So let's say you have the words like

> ずっと [zutto]
>
> のって [notte]

How would you write these words if you would pronounce them? Is it like **zut-to** or **zu-tto** or maybe **zu-t-to**?

Comment: Do you mean writing it down mora by mora? I will admit, this question was a bit difficult to wrap my head around.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Repeating the vowel sound of the mora that precedes gemination in songs](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3540/repeating-the-vowel-sound-of-the-mora-that-precedes-gemination-in-songs)

Comment: Do you know how to pronounce ずっと and are asking how best to write it in *rōmaji*? Or are you trying to understand how to pronounce ずっと by looking at a romanization *zutto*? (Or are you trying to ask something else?)

Comment: @Earthliŋ Well as you can see, I'm having a hard time really formulating what the issue is, but I think the it's mainly the pronounciation with respect to how you would "split" it for karaoke purposes. For example if you hear a song with the word `ずっと`, how would you split the letters in romanized form? Like `zu-t-to` or `zu-tto` or `zut-to`? I've seen many people doing `zu-tto`, which makes sense in a way that the `tt` are connected then. But then again, I thought the `っ` would make the pronounciation longer for the letter `u` in `ず `, so `zu-t-to` would make more sense to me then.

Comment: Take a look at the linked question from broccoli forest, where it is explained how gemination is pronounced in songs. How you want to represent this in a romanization is up to you — splitting up romanized words mora by mora by inserting hyphens is not part of standard romanization systems. Besides, you want it to work for songs... I'm not sure this is on-topic, but I'll let the community decide.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you really need...**zu-tto**. Because in this word **zu** is one syllable (and you can often hear loooong **u** for big emphasize e.g. in anime, so this split looks more natural) and **tto** another, 'cause little っ duplicates the sound t in **to** syllable, but has no pronunciation itself.